# matplotlib: generate a new graph in a new window for subsequent program runs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a Python program that generates graphs using matplotlib. I am trying to get the program to generate a bunch of plots in one program run (the user is asked if they want to generate another graph) all in separate windows. Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 23):

To generate a new figure, you can add plt.figure() before any plotting that your program does.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_plot(slope):
    x = np.arange(1,10)
    y = slope*x+3
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)

make_plot(2)
make_plot(3)
```

Comment: See my answer, this is not the pattern that the mpl devs suggest, see http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Comment: I see your point, but when I use your code, matplotlib doesn't draw any of the axes until after another=False.

Comment: See edits to my answer.  This is related to if you have `plt.ion()` called or not which affects how aggressively mpl ties to the gui event loop.

Answer (score 15):

Using the latest matlibplot, I found the following to work for my purposes:

```
# create figure (will only create new window if needed)
plt.figure()
# Generate plot1
plt.plot(range(10, 20))
# Show the plot in non-blocking mode
plt.show(block=False)

# create figure (will only create new window if needed)
plt.figure()
# Generate plot2
plt.plot(range(10, 20))
# Show the plot in non-blocking mode
plt.show(block=False)

...

# Finally block main thread until all plots are closed
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to ensure all of your lines go to the correct figure window is something like:

```
from six.moves import input
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
another = True
while another:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot(range(5))


    fig.canvas.manager.show() 
    # this makes sure that the gui window gets shown
    # if this is needed depends on rcparams, this is just to be safe
    fig.canvas.flush_events() 
    # this make sure that if the event loop integration is not 
    # set up by the gui framework the plot will update

    another = bool(input("would you like another? "))
```

If you want to run this with a non-gui backend you will need to drop the `flush_events` call or wrap it in a `try: ... except NotImplementedError`.  Much of this complication is defensive programming because GUIs can be difficult and the behavior of this code may be dependent on many factors which are not obvious from the code shown.

Using the implicit axes of `pyplot` can cause problems as the 'current axes' is set by the last axes the user clicked on.  You should really only use `pyplot` when interactively typing at the rpel and almost never (other than `plt.subplots`) in scripts/programs.

Comment: While I believe it's the best answer, I'm distracted from the main message by the level of complexity that was added with the update. Does this would have been ok to add `fig.show()` instead of the entire `try` statement for the sake of this minimal example?

Comment: @Jean-SébastienGosselin Fair point, demoted that information to a comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.figure()` function to create a new window, the following code makes two windows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))  # Creates the plot.  No need to save the current figure.
plt.draw()  # Draws, but does not block

plt.figure()  # New window, if needed.  No need to save it, as pyplot uses the concept of current figure
plt.plot(range(10, 20))
plt.draw()
```

You can repeat this as many times as you want

Comment: `plt.figure` is a function not a method and always creates a new window, `plt.gcf()` uses the current one.

Comment: @tcaswell right, function sorry for the confusion. I think the OP wants new windows so `plt.gcf()` is not what they want and should use `plt.figure()`

Comment: I know what the OP wants but there are incorrect / not quite correct statements in your answer.

Comment: @tacaswell Do not know what is so wrong about it. I wanted to find out how I could create a new window that is separate from anything before. And this is the answer to it (as well as the accepted answer also says: plt.figure(). Upvote.